# Write Wave header and Add Data, without closing ofstream

Tags: c++, iostream, wav

As topic says, here is the code:

```
    template <typename SampleType>
void writeWAVHeader
(
char const* outFile,
SampleType* buf,
int sizeMult,
size_t bufSize,
int sampleRate,
short channels,
int Flush
)
{ 
    if (sizeMult != 0)
        bufSize = bufSize*sizeMult;

        std::ofstream stream(outFile, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);
    stream.seekp(0);
    stream.write("RIFF", 4);
    write<int>(stream, 36 + bufSize);
    stream.write("WAVE", 4);
    stream.write("fmt ", 4);
    write<int>(stream, 16);
    writeFormat<SampleType>(stream);                                // Format
    write<short>(stream, channels);                                 // Channels
    write<int>(stream, sampleRate);                                 // Sample Rate
    write<int>(stream, sampleRate * channels * sizeof(SampleType)); // Byterate
    write<short>(stream, channels * sizeof(SampleType));            // Frame size
    write<short>(stream, 8 * sizeof(SampleType));                   // Bits per sample
    stream.write("data", 4);
    stream.write((const char*)&bufSize, 4);
    stream.seekp(stream.end);
    if(sizeMult != 0)
        bufSize = bufSize/sizeMult;
    stream.write((const char*)buf, bufSize);
    stream.flush();
    if (Flush >= 100)
    stream.close();
}
```

You can see the commented out stuff I have been trying.

In my mind, this should be easy.

I open the file with these parameters, seek to the beginning, write the header, then seek to the end, as i am appending to the wave as well as rewriting the header, but it won't work.  It simply rewrites the whole thing all the time.

The code is how it looks like when it works. I have to close and reopen, which, for me, makes no sense in this case.

**UPDATE:**

I changed the code, and this is NOT working as expected, which i find confusing.

I seekp(0) = beginning of the file.

Write the header.

Seek to the end of the file,.

Add new audio data.

Comment: Can you expand on "it simply rewrites the whole thing all the time"? Does your file end up truncated? i.e. what is being rewritten?

Comment: Is it just a typo in your post, or you actually used "|| std::ios::app" (instead of "| std::ios::app") when creating the stream ?

Comment: @noelicus I mean, it truncates (i think it just write the header and the audio (the first loop, which is small), then rewrites it, so it only get's like 4kb. - Isn't it supposed to be 2 ||, does it make any difference? - Oh noticed i had | before that.. hmm wonder if it matters.. - Okay it seems the || makes me able to write. The Wave file don't work as expected however, it thinks it's only 10ms (one loop of data) long, which is weird, the header should be rewritten accordingly

Comment: | is a bitwise OR. A very big difference! - you need 1 |

Comment: I knew it was, but i thought it only mattered in "If, While stuff", care to explain how it works in these cases, i mean there wasn't any "true/false" things that could trigger it? - Also code is updated - Checked the Wav file, it seems that the Header is NOT rewritten, but added along with the audio data, which means seekp(0) doesn't work.

Comment: For the |, they're different flags which are packed into different bit positions hence why you need a bitwise OR. 
For your remaining issue, if you send a constant number of samples to your function, the data will get appended, however the header will always be updated with that constant sample count. You need to keep track of the total samples and update the header with that.

Comment: @SleuthEye , Ah ok. The Sample data (Length of the stream) is updated, that's the buffer*multisize, (i increase an int each loop), and also / multisize when i write the data to make it correct again. - The only issue is that the header is not rewritten, it's appending.

Comment: you should remove std::ios::app altogether.

Comment: Then it will truncate the file (even if i tell it to start writing at the end). Got any solution for that?

Comment: Read header on first open.

Comment: How does that help, you mean i should read the header and the file content, rewrite the header, add the new data, then overwrite the file?

Comment: Not quite. Read the header to get #samples on 1st open, then overwrite header with sample count (including initial #samples + new) and append samples. std::ofstream does not automatically truncates the file unless you specify std::ios::trunc flag.

Comment: @SleuthEye , but the sample length (the size which decides the Wave length) isn't the problem here. The thing is, i can't decide where to write. Even if i say seekp(0), it won't write at that position (Start?), and the file will be deleted on each start Except if i use ::app , never used Trunc, but read that it deletes, but makes no sense as it does this anyway for me (or well not delete, it erases all content). You can try it yourself

Comment: Okay i may have solved it, the culprit is "stream.seekp(stream.end); ", stream.end does NOT send me to the end, i checked and i rewrite the header then some data, and repeat (without ::app), so it's as you say, it doesn't delete the file content, it's just that i rewrite it. Need to find a way to seek to the end now.

Comment: If you use std::ios::app it always writes at end, so seekp(0) is ineffective in that case. If you don't use std::ios::app, seekp(0) puts you at the start of the file so you can overwrite header, then seekp(0, std::ios::end) puts you back at the end of the file so you can append.

Comment: It seems i had to write it differently, i will put an answer with the working code, please check it out, there may be mistakes anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part of you problem lies with the use of the `std::ios::app` flag. As indicated in [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode):

> app    seek to the end of stream before each write

Hence if you use this option, header and data alike will get appended at the end of the file, irrespective of `seekp(0)` calls. You should thus open your stream with:

```
std::ofstream stream(outFile, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
```

The other part of your problem is with the usage of `seekp`. When called with a single argument `seekp` interpret the constant `std::ios::end` (after some type conversion) as the absolute position into the file (with respect to the start of file), instead of using the offset corresponding to the end of the file.

So you should change the line:

```
stream.seekp(stream.end)
```

to:

```
steam.seekp(0, stream.end);
```

Comment: Seems you wrote what i fixed in my own answer, will however give you the Answer mark as you were the one helping me get to it:)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working code that does as it's intended.
There May be something wrong with it, but if no one says anything, then this is most likely the answer for my question.

```
template <>
void writeFormat<float>(std::ofstream& stream) {
    write<short>(stream, 3);
}


template <typename SampleType>
void writeWAVHeader
(
char const* outFile,
SampleType* buf,
int sizeMult,
size_t bufSize,
int sampleRate,
short channels,
int Flush
)
{ 
    if (sizeMult != 0)
        bufSize = bufSize*sizeMult;


    std::ofstream stream(outFile, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

    stream.write("RIFF", 4);
    write<int>(stream, 36 + bufSize);
    stream.write("WAVE", 4);
    stream.write("fmt ", 4);
    write<int>(stream, 16);
    writeFormat<SampleType>(stream);                                // Format
    write<short>(stream, channels);                                 // Channels
    write<int>(stream, sampleRate);                                 // Sample Rate
    write<int>(stream, sampleRate * channels * sizeof(SampleType)); // Byterate
    write<short>(stream, channels * sizeof(SampleType));            // Frame size
    write<short>(stream, 8 * sizeof(SampleType));                   // Bits per sample
    stream.write("data", 4);
    stream.write((const char*)&bufSize, 4);
    stream.seekp(0,stream.end);
    if(sizeMult != 0)
        bufSize = bufSize/sizeMult;
    stream.write((const char*)buf, bufSize);
    stream.flush();
    if (Flush >= 100) //Prevent close on each run.
        {
        stream.close();

    }

}
```